# Start Sql Server Agent

Tags: sql-server

I just got SQL Server 2008 Enterprise edition, but I can't start the Agent XPS service. I looked over surface area configuration and tried to change the service start mode from Disabled to Automatic (in the SQL Server configuration manager) and there I generated an error message:

> The remote procedure cannot be completed.

The error code is 0X800706be, I didn't change any setting and I'm connecting to the server with windows authentication, what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: anyone have an idea? mabye i've missed some configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the logon account for the SQL Agent service has the "Logon as a service" rights specified in "Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 2005 installed also? There are too many common things like DLL(s) that are being used by both 2005 and 2008 to have them both running on the same machine and not have any problems.